# Why is my charms bar on Windows 8.1 not vertically centered?

Tags: windows-8.1, parallels, charms-bar

I am using Parallels VM to run Windows 8.1, and here's my charms bar:

[image: Charms bar not vertically centered]

Why is this happening? How can I fix it? Thanks.

P.S. Sorry for the big picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you open the Charmsbar by putting the mouse to the right button corner. If you move it to the right top corner it would be near to the top o the screen. This is a change in Windows 8.1.

Comment: oh, I see. Is there a way for me to keep it in the center?

Comment: open the charmsbar with the shortcut Win-Key+C. does it open it in the center?

Comment: Hmm, I can't tell - the windows key + c got disabled... anyway, thanks for the help - I understand that now. I was used to smaller monitors, so on my 1920x1080 iMac, I couldn't understand why the charms bar wasn't in the middle.

Comment: is there a way to disable this?

Comment: @think123 open the Charmsbar with Touch swipe (if you have touch) or via Win+C. In both cases it is centered.